# JComboBox to string

Tags: java, swing, combobox, jcombobox

I have a String array of names, and then I added it into an editable JComboBox.

The user can either pick his/her name from the choices or just input his/her name if not in the choices.

How do I put the user input into a new string variable?

```
   String [] chooseName = { Mark, John, Allison, Jessica };
   JComboBox combo = new JComboBox (chooseName);
   combo.setEditable(true);

   String chosenName =  /*  how do i place what the user inputed here? */
```

Answer (score 5):

I would add an action listener to the combo box. By doing it in the same block there, it will simply grab the default (I believe). This way we make sure we grab the value once selected.

```
String [] chooseName = { Mark, John, Allison, Jessica };
final JComboBox combo = new JComboBox (chooseName);
combo.setEditable(true);
combo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String chosenName =  (String) combo.getSelectedItem();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

`combo.getSelectedItem()`

Answer (score 1):

This will Help You..

```
combo.getSelectedItem();
```

For More reference follow this link, it will help you..

http://www.roseindia.net/java/example/java/swing/ComboBox.shtml